# Lifting into data constructor using record syntax?

Tags: haskell

I have the following type:

```
data Person a = {name :: String, age :: Int, injury :: Injury a}

data Injury a = Physical a | Mental a
```

I'm trying to create a function that lifts an injury into a instance of a person:

```
liftInjury :: Person a -> Injury a -> Person a
liftInjury person inj = person {injury = int}

class Hospital i where
  admit :: Person a  -> i -> Person a

instance Hospital (Injury a) where
  admin person inj = liftInjury person inj -- ERROR
```

Error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘a1’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the instance declaration
```

Is this being caused because the compiler doesn't know that `a` denied in `liftInjury` is the same as the `a` in `instance Hospital (Injury a) ...` ?

What's the best solution for this?

Comment: I think you could use something like a functional dependency in your hospital class. But right now I don't have time to write a full answer

Comment: Why does `Hospital` need to be a class?

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I need the functions within to be able take multiple data types.. `Injury a`, `Complication a`, etc...

Comment: I think you've overcomplicated your design. I don't think you need all those type parameters, or the `Hospital` class. Keep it simple. What's wrong with something like `data Patient = Patient { name :: String, injuries :: [Injury], complications :: [Complication] }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this with multi-parameter type classes, which would allow you to place constraints on both the type of the `Person` and the type of the `Injury`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class Hospital i p where
    admit :: Person p -> i -> Person p

instance Hospital (Injury a) a where
    admit person inj = liftInjury person inj
```

Adding the type parameter of `Person` to the class definition lets you place constraints on it within the `instance` declaration, which allows you to make sure the type parameter of the `Person` and the `Injury` are the same.

A simpler option would be to change `Hospital` to take the type parameter of the injury instead of the injury type itself:

```
class Hospital a where
    admit :: Person a -> Injury a -> Person a
```

...but I imagine the rest of your system precludes that option.